# Wordpress CPT save metadata in gutenberg

Tags: custom-post-types, sidebar, block-editor

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new sidebar api vs metabox issue when trying to come up with how to save metadata for a custom post type. I've got a couple websites I'm going to be creating that will use multiple custom post types that I will be creating: Events, FAQ, Enrollments, Sponsors, to name a few.

I had gotten understanding how to make CPTs and create metaboxes to save metadata not long before wordpress released 5.0 and Gutenberg. I have read about how metaboxes are on their way to obsolescence and that creating sidebars are the way of the future for saving metadata.

A couple questions for best practices:

1. Should I be using the sidebar or metaboxes
2. If sidebar, should I be putting the metadata inputs in the default sidebar or making a custom sidebar?
3. If I should be doing a custom sidebar, is there a way to make that be the default sidebar displayed?

**Update 12/30/19** I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348145/display-different-gutenberg-template-from-selected-post-attributes) which mentions a link to the Block editor handbook about [block templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-templates/). It appears that I should be able to make a series of custom block types to accept meta data within this block template for that custom post type and lock down the block template with the template_lock property. Is this a better approach than using the sidebar for inputting metadata?